# AppBarLayout elevation disappears when recreating the activity

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-appbarlayout

AppBarLayout elevation disappears after recreating the activity.I am using the latest support library 25.0.1

Before recreating the activity
[image]

After recreating the activity
[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="muhammad.ibrahim.alkady.quran.radio.activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/apl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/ctl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="center"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title.Inverse"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="center"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title.Inverse"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/t"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: add this in appbar xml:  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:stateListAnimator="@animator/appbar_elevated"

Comment: and the appbar_elevated animator ? Thanks.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: Sorry. Until now I couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` if you have mentioned it in your 
`<application>` tag inside AndroidManifest.xml.